# Class cannot be instantiated

Tags: java

I have created a class by the name of Account. I am then instantiating an object of the type class. All the code is saved in the file TestAccount. But the system gives me an error as shown below

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at testaccount.TestAccount.main(TestAccount.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - class Account is public, should be declared in a file named Account.java
>       at testaccount.Account.(TestAccount.java:20)
>       ... 1 more
>   Java Result: 1

Below is my code:

```
package testaccount;

public class TestAccount
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Account Account1=new Account();
Account1.setId(1122);
Account1.setBalance(20000);
Account1.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
System.out.println("The monthly interest rate is " + Account1.getMonthlyInterestRate());
System.out.println("The balance after the withdrawal is "+ Account1.withdraw(2000));
System.out.println("The balabce after the deposit is " + Account1.deposit(3000));

}

}

public class Account 
   {
      private int id;
      private double balance;
      private double annualInterestRate;
      private static long dateCreated;

      public Account()
      {
          id=0;
          balance=0;
          annualInterestRate=0;
          dateCreated=System.currentTimeMillis();
      }

      public Account(int newId,double newBalance)
      {
          id=newId;
          balance=newBalance;
      }

      public int getId()
      {
          return id;
      }
      public void setId(int newId)
      {
           id=newId;
      }

      public double getbalance()
      {
          return balance;
      }
      public void setBalance(double newBalance)
      {
           balance=newBalance;
      }

      public double getAnnualInterestRate()
      {
          return annualInterestRate;
      }
      public void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate)
      {
           annualInterestRate=newAnnualInterestRate;
      }

      public static long getDateCreate()
      {
          return dateCreated;
      }

      public double getMonthlyInterestRate()
      {
          return (annualInterestRate/12);
      }

      public double withdraw(double newWithdraw)
      {
          return (balance-newWithdraw);
      }

      public double deposit(double deposit)
      {
          return (balance+deposit);
      }
}
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have 2 separated public classes in a single java file.

Comment: The error message is giving you a hint: `class Account is public, should be declared in a file named Account.java`

Comment: How can I link the two files Account.java and Testaccount.java then?

Comment: With an [`import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) statement!

Comment: Just instantiate new Account object. Simple as that.

Comment: you dont have to `import` if they are in the same package

Comment: @Epicblood Ah right, I rarely work with classes in the same package, so I forget that rule.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a new file called `Account.java` and put your account class in there. this is because when you call account from another class, the jvm will go looking for `Account.class` and if your account class is in a file named `TestAccount.class` it wont be able to find it.

Otherwise the compiler wont compile your file

As long as both your classes are in the same package (folder) you don't have to do anything special to "link" the two.

Unless, of course, you want to nest the classes, in which case you put your `Account` class inside of your `TestAccount` class. Although I do not recommend this as it is very messy.

Comment: It's not necessary to create new java file. He could just define `Account` class within `TestAccount` class.

Comment: Updated answer, didn't want to mention that as I learned that is bad coding practice and messy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good pratice, and the solutions already present are better but you can move the Account class inside the TestAccount and make it static (put static in front of the class definition). That'll also work.